# For a vector, determine the index past which all values are NA (or some value)

Tags: r, na, missing-data

So, I have survey data where I want to address the issue of multiple administrations of the survey (computer failed, browser closed, and people restarted).  Say I have cases x1 and x2, done by the same person in that order (here, already pulled out as vectors)

```
x1 <- c(1:35, rep(NA, 65))
x2 <- c(-1:-95, rep(NA, 5))
```

Given that I can know x1 occurred first, I want to identify the first NA in x1 past which all further entries are NA (position 36), so I can combine the cases to generate data representing first impressions only.

I'd like to find a function that would enable me to do this:

```
n <- {function that computes this value}
x <- c(x1[1:(n-1)], x2[n:length(x2)])
```

resulting in output here equivalent to:

```
c(1:35, -36:-95, rep(NA, 5))
```

approaches like `length(na.omit(x1)) + 1` will not work, as there may be NA's prior to the ending point, disrupting the indexing.  For instance, it would still need to find index 36 if

```
 x1 <- c(1:12, NA, 13:35, rep(NA, 65))
```

97% needing this to work just for NA's, but a general solution would be great, too (i.e., something that could also match "" or something similar, if needed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using run-length-encoding

```
n <- with(rle(is.na(x1)), lengths[length(lengths) -1 ] + 1 )

x <- c(x1[1:(n-1)], x2[n:length(x2)])

# [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
# [30]  30  31  32  33  34  35 -36 -37 -38 -39 -40 -41 -42 -43 -44 -45 -46 -47 -48 -49 -50 -51 -52 -53 -54 -55 -56 -57 -58
# [59] -59 -60 -61 -62 -63 -64 -65 -66 -67 -68 -69 -70 -71 -72 -73 -74 -75 -76 -77 -78 -79 -80 -81 -82 -83 -84 -85 -86 -87
# [88] -88 -89 -90 -91 -92 -93 -94 -95  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

as `rle` gives the lengths of runs of `NA` (or whatever you specify). And, you want to use the last of these runs, so we can pick the starting point of the last run

```
> rle(is.na(x1))
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:2] 35 65
  values : logi [1:2] FALSE TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

**Data from your question**

```
x1 <- c(1:35, rep(NA, 65))
x2 <- c(-1:-95, rep(NA, 5))
n <- max( which(diff(is.na(x1)) == 1)) 
c(x1[1:n-1], x2[n:length(x2)])

# [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
# [24]  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34 -35 -36 -37 -38 -39 -40 -41 -42 -43 -44 -45 -46
# [47] -47 -48 -49 -50 -51 -52 -53 -54 -55 -56 -57 -58 -59 -60 -61 -62 -63 -64 -65 -66 -67 -68 -69
# [70] -70 -71 -72 -73 -74 -75 -76 -77 -78 -79 -80 -81 -82 -83 -84 -85 -86 -87 -88 -89 -90 -91 -92
# [93] -93 -94 -95  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

**Another Example:**

```
x1 <- c(1:35, rep(NA, 35), 1:20, rep(NA, 10))
x2 <- c(-1:-95, rep(NA, 5))
n <- max( which(diff(is.na(x1)) == 1)) 
c(x1[1:n-1], x2[n:length(x2)])
# [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
# [24]  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# [47]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# [70]  NA   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19 -90 -91 -92
# [93] -93 -94 -95  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: Clever chaining of basic functions there.  +1 to you, and possibly the award, though I'll leave it open for a bit to see if any other solutions appear.

Comment: @Joe - I don't see how this matches the output you required?

Comment: exactly. @Joe please update your original query. it's bit confusing now.

Comment: Sathish's output is actually incorrect, as it should be:

`c( x1[1: (max( which(diff( is.na(x1) ) == 1) )-1) ], 
   x2[max( which(diff( is.na(x2) ) == 1) ) : length(x2) ] ) ` 

However, the `max( which(diff( is.na(x1) ) == 1) )` does capture only the final run of NA's, due to the max() wrapping, which was the thing I was looking for

Comment: Sorry, slight correction `c(x1[1:(max( which(diff(is.na(x1)) == 1))-1)], x2[max(which(diff(is.na(x1)) == 1)):length(x2)])` produces the correct output.  Or `n <-  max( which(diff(is.na(x1)) == 1)) ; c(x1[1:n-1], x2[n:length(x2)])`

Comment: @Joe can you please explain where is the result difference between these two queries? `max( which(diff( is.na(x1) ) == 1) )` and `(head(which(is.na(x1)),1) - 1)`.

Comment: Also now check this,
your query output
`x1[1:(max( which(diff(is.na(x1)) == 1))-1)]
 [1]  1  2  3 ... 33 34`
and my query output
`> x1[1:(head(which(is.na(x1)),1) - 1)]
 [1]  1  2  ... 33 34 35`
you wanted till 35, isn't it?

Comment: I think instead of `x1[1:n-1]` this should work `x1[1:n]`. But the main idea of finding the last run of NA will work for most cases. Please try your solution with the data from second example.

Comment: @Sathish it's perfectly working for 2nd set of data. Why do you need to give max when checking for first NA position in a list. Please correct me if I am understanding the requirement wrong. user need first check of "NA" in vector. Isn't it?

Comment: @Zico I will explain it with the data in the second example. Please look at `x1`. It has `NA` running for some length two times. OP wants to find the last run of `NA` (it starts at index 90 ) and use it as an index to extract the values of `x1` and `x2`

Comment: @Sathish I can see user wanted this `I want to identify the first NA in x1 past which all further entries are NA (position 36)`. and my code finds only first arrival of `NA` not 2nd or last. where is the problem?

Comment: my code is working fine with your second data set. please run from your end once.

Answer (score 0):

You almost solved the query by yourself. Try this please

```
x3 <- c(x1[1:(head(which(is.na(x1)),1) - 1)], x2[head(which(is.na(x1)),1):length(x2)])
```

I hope you can convert it to function.

Comment: Sorry, but this just finds the first NA, which as I stated isn't the goal.  If x1 were, say

     x1 <- c(1:25, NA, 27:35, rep(NA, 65))

this would work totally differently.  And making head() longer wouldn't work, either--I need NA's of arbitrary length (from some point until the end).

Comment: @Joe you wrote this in your query `Given that I can know x1 occurred first, I want to identify the first NA in x1 past which all further entries are NA (position 36), so I can combine the cases to generate data representing first impressions only. ` also your `sample output` does not reflect your current query. can you please update your `sample output`

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with a very simple `ifelse`:

```
x3 = ifelse(is.na(x1),x2,x1)
```

Result:

```
> x3
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13
 [14]  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26
 [27]  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35 -36 -37 -38 -39
 [40] -40 -41 -42 -43 -44 -45 -46 -47 -48 -49 -50 -51 -52
 [53] -53 -54 -55 -56 -57 -58 -59 -60 -61 -62 -63 -64 -65
 [66] -66 -67 -68 -69 -70 -71 -72 -73 -74 -75 -76 -77 -78
 [79] -79 -80 -81 -82 -83 -84 -85 -86 -87 -88 -89 -90 -91
 [92] -92 -93 -94 -95  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

This works if you dont have NAs before the last valid entry in x1. If this were the case, a previous NA could mean that the user skipped the question. If you want to keep previous NAs inside x1, do:

```
lastValidX1 =  max(which(!is.na(x1)))
x3 = c( x1[1:lastValidX1] , x2[(lastValidX1+1):length(x2)] )
```

Example:

```
x1 <- c(1:19,NA,21:35, rep(NA, 65))
x2 <- c(-1:-95, rep(NA, 5))

lastValidX1 =  max(which(!is.na(x1)))
x3 = c( x1[1:lastValidX1] , x2[(lastValidX1+1):length(x2)] )

> x3
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13
 [14]  14  15  16  17  18  19  NA  21  22  23  24  25  26
 [27]  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35 -36 -37 -38 -39
 [40] -40 -41 -42 -43 -44 -45 -46 -47 -48 -49 -50 -51 -52
 [53] -53 -54 -55 -56 -57 -58 -59 -60 -61 -62 -63 -64 -65
 [66] -66 -67 -68 -69 -70 -71 -72 -73 -74 -75 -76 -77 -78
 [79] -79 -80 -81 -82 -83 -84 -85 -86 -87 -88 -89 -90 -91
 [92] -92 -93 -94 -95  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA

> lastValidX1
[1] 35
```

Comment: I don't think this will solve the "I want to identify the first NA in x1 past which all further entries are NA (position 36)" bit

Comment: If the user is allowed to skip questions (NAs between valid answers), how would you know that the user did not skip one or more answers after the last valid entry?